# Incomplete statement at end of file

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

After running below command :

```
sh cqlsh --request-timeout=3600 -f test.cql
```

I am getting below error :

```
Incomplete statement at end of file
```

Even when my first line is **use sample;** followed by 50 insert queries.

What could be the reasons for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is returned if the statement at the end of the file either (a) has invalid syntax, or (b) not terminated correctly.

Sometimes the issue can occur several lines up from the last statement in the input file.

Check that the CQL statements have valid syntax. It might be necessary to do a process of elimination and split the file so there's only 10 statements in each so you can identify the offending statement. Cheers!